# img scale to viewport inside div

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I'm building an image lightbox with a close button. The Image should scale to it's default size until it hits a maximum of 90% page width/height.
This works fine with smaller images than the maximum, anything above will overflow the container div.

Here is my codepen example: 
https://codepen.io/gempir/pen/eMYmyx

How do I force the image to scale?

Setting

```
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Does not help because the parent div has no fixed width. Any idea how to handle this situation correctly, besides using JS to calculate on the fly.

```css
.image-overlay {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-overlay .image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 90% !important;
  max-height: 90% !important;
  background: blue;
}

.image-overlay .image-container .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px;
}

.image-overlay .image-container img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-overlay">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1800/1800">
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use viewport units instead:

```css
.image-overlay {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-overlay .image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 90% !important;
  max-height: 90% !important;
  background: blue;
}

.image-overlay .image-container .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px;
}

.image-overlay .image-container img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-overlay">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1800/1800">
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will restrict your image based on the actual viewport available, instead of the container, your image is in.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdNVWV)

Comment: This is the best solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use vmin and vmax to deal with this if you want to change behaviour depending on the viewport.

```css
.image-overlay {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .25);
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
  .image-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
    
  }  
    .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      right: 5px;
      color: white;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 90vmin;
      max-height: 90vmin;

    }
```

```html
<div class="image-overlay">
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1800/1800">
  <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Explanation:

vmin = 1%of min viewport size (width or height, equals to vh or vw depending on which one is the smaller)

vmax = the opposite of vmin.

what can vmin and vmax do?

you can use vh and vw (or % depending on the situation) to resize images, but sometimes they look too small on smartphones, so you can use:

```
   .images{
        max-width: 90vmin;
        max-height: 90vmin;
    }
    @media(max-width:600px){
       .images{
           max-width: 90vmax;
           max-height: 90vmax;
        }
    }
```

they'll fit well on computer viewports (or even smart TV etc) and will be a bit bigger on smartphones.

Comment: This works for images that are too wide, but not for images where the height is too much

Comment: As it's supposed to work as isdue to responsiveness (screen size is the limit for width, and there's no limit for height) if you want to resize images you must change your title and question to include image resize words for being more accurated.

Comment: My post says:  "The Image should scale to it's default size until it hits a maximum of 90% page width/height" so I did say it beforehand. An Image should not go beyond the page.

Comment: please, edit the post title in order that other users can find well the issue. it's not an overflow issue. That's the default behaviour, not an your issue. Only add image resize to your title. I'll edit the answer with a different option to choose.

Comment: Sorry if the title confused you I have updated it. It was bad due to me misunderstanding the issue. Now I get that's not an issue of overflowing.

Comment: no problem, it's only for the users with the same issue to find it quick, i edited the answer giving another solution. Good luck with your project! :)